# Can I define an Enum per rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

My rails app has three production environments. One of my rails models has an enum called search_group and I want the values to be different per environment.

Currently:
`enum search_group: [:all_news, :all_lifestyle, :all_sports, :all_arts, :all_opinion, :all_columns]`

How can I set these to be independent per environment?

Comment: which three environments do you have?

Comment: There is a production, production_journal, and production_prt as well as staging with the same format.

Comment: if that is the case then `split("_")[0]` will return `"production"` always, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You would be correct. Alas in my hast to comment above I mixed up the variable name. Correctly written it is `journal_production`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining the enum as a function then checking the Rails env I can get different enums.

```
def self.env_search_groups
  case Rails.env.split("_")[0]
  when "journal"
    [:all_news, :all_lifestyle, :all_sports, :all_community, :all_living, :all_opinion, :all_columns]
  when "prt"
    [:all_news]
  else
    [:all_news, :all_lifestyle, :all_sports, :all_arts, :all_opinion, :all_columns]
  end
end

enum search_group: env_search_groups
```

The method must be defined before the enum can use it.

Comment: you could also do something like: `if Rails.env.production_journal?..elsif Rails.env.production_prt? else...end`

Comment: That would be ok if it was just production, but we also have `staging_journal` and `staging_prt` environments.